# Custom delete button for UITextField on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I am making an iPad app that has a key board with extra large buttons fixed on the screen at all times.  The outputted text is being displayed into a Text Field and everything works fine except the delete button I have created.  I originally set the text to be displayed in a text view and the delete button worked fine, but when I changed it into a text field it stopped working unless the apple keyboard is on the screen.  Here is the code I am using for the delete button

```
- (IBAction)del:(id)sender 
{

    [textField deleteBackward];

}
```

My question is how do I get my delete button to work in the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a hint to this issue may be in the documentation for `deleteBackward` which says:

> Remove the character just before the cursor from your class’s backing
>   store and redisplay the text.

If the keyboard is not on screen (and the textfield is not the first responder), then there is no cursor so that might be why it doesn't work. If all you want to do is delete the last character you could just do it manually by doing something like this:

```
- (IBAction)del:(id)sender 
{
  textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:textField.text.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works awesome! I was way overthinking this.  This is the complete code I implemented inside the IBAction                       if([textField.text length]>0)                                             { NSUInteger lastCharIndex= [textField.text length]                      textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:lastCharIndex - 1];     Hopefully that will help anyone else who has this problem